# Using LINQ expressions for custom data types

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In my "settings" dialog box i have two list boxes which look like this:

```
+------+   +---------+
|File  |   |Extension|
|type  |   |         |
|      |   |         |
+------+   +---------+
```

I have some data that needs to be loaded from XML, so i made a class for that:

```
public class XmlConfig
{
    public List<config> con = new List<config>();
    public XmlConfig(string PathToSettings)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(PathToSettings);
        XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ext");
        foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in xmlNodes)                          
            con.Add(new config()
            {
                FolderName = xmlnode.Attributes["File"].Value,
                Extensions = xmlnode.InnerText.Split(',').ToList<string>()
            });
    }
}

public struct config
{
    public string FolderName;
    public List<string> Extensions;
}
```

now i want to fill the folderlistbox with all the values in the xml file and that is happening correctly but the problem is that i want it to be like when the file type list item is clicked the corresponding extensions should be displayed and i have no idea about how to do that. somebody suggested to use linq but since i am new to c# i have no idea what it is.

Comment: Can you clarify "when the file type list item is clicked the corresponding extensions should be displayed"? clicked **where** and displayed **where**? btw, this seems to have nothing to do with LINQ at all...

Comment: sorry for not being clear. the file type list item is clicked in the first list box and the corresponding extension should be displayed in extension list box. if you use launchy go to its  catalog settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to fileTypes ListView event SelectedValueChanged and then in handler of that event filter the Extensions collection and bind to another ListBox

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //get selected config object
            config conf = listBox1.SelectedItem as config;

            //fill extensions listbox
            listBox2.DataSource = config.Extensions;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry this doesnt work. maybe some changes have to be made to the xmlconfig class for this to work

Comment: i got it to work as you forgot to mension that i had to set that i had to set the listbox items from conf data types as well

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a way to do it. plz correct me if i am wrong...

```
  private void folderListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            extListBox.Items.Clear();
            string selectVal = folderListBox.GetItemText(folderListBox.SelectedItem);            
            //var extn = from ext in configData.con where ext.FolderName == folderListBox.SelectedValue select ext;
            var extn = from ext in configData.con where ext.FolderName == selectVal select ext;
            //var result = List 
            foreach (var ext in extn)
            {
                foreach (string extension in ext.Extensions)
                    extListBox.Items.Add(extension);
            }                
        }
```

before this i was doing

```
 var extn = from ext in configData.con where ext.FolderName == selectVal select ext.Extensions;
```

but it showed an error.